# EOF BOF not consistence.. exception even Recordset has RecordCount more than one only on one machine out of seven

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, com, vb6, adodb

We have an application with .Net 4.7 as WebAPI and some of the crital business logic is in VB6-COM.

ADODB interop DLL is used to pass recordset to COM object to perform further business logic.

Using SQL Server 2012R2.

Below is C# code

```
Recordset recordSet;
recordSet = metaData.GetMetadata();
....
....
//This method adds two rows in iteration
FillDefaultTwoRows(recordSet); 

// COM object processes the recordset and this error out with EOF BOF
// even after having minimum one row in it.
dataManager.Process(recordSet);
```

Before making call to `dataManager.Process(recordSet);` if we call `recordSet.MoveFirst()` application do not error out with EOF and BOF is true exception else it always throw the EOF BOF is true.

The surprise is, exception comes *only one machine out of seven*, we check .net version, windows update, worker pool setting in IIS all are same. Connection string remains same for both machines, ADODB, ADO and VBVM versions are all same.

**Same code deployed in two machines and here is the log from each**

Machine A: Received ADODB.Recordset has BOF=False and EOF=False

Machine B: Received ADODB.Recordset has BOF=False and EOF=True

**Machine-B is facing exception and machine A is not.**

**The biggest question we have what makes this record position reset?**

Is there any system level/global config or setting needed to resolve this exception without code change?

Comment: True @Charlieface but to not impact business, the current priority to reuse for short term.

Comment: If you think that's a VB6 problem, you should add the relevant VB6 code to your question.

Comment: How are you certain that you have exactly the same scenario on the problematic PC? Could something else be different? Like a DB connection string? Input data?  Personally I would want to throw in some debug logging right around the call which fails to make sure of that.;

Comment: @StayOnTarget Same code deployed in two machines and here is the log from each, for the same code what has been put above. Machine A: Received ADODB.Recordset has BOF=False and EOF=False. Machine B: Received ADODB.Recordset has BOF=False and EOF=True. Machine-B is facing exception and machine A is not. The biggest question we have what makes this record position reset?

Comment: Some thing to try: Run a SQL Profiler trace and compare the configuration properties of the 2 connections when they are established. Reinstall ADODB via the MDAC redistributable.

Comment: Still no VB6 code shown. If I understand you right, doing a `MoveFirst` in the C# assembly, the error does not occur. Well, than that's sloopy VB6 programming. A simple `If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then rs.MoveFirst` there should solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexK. connection string remains same for both machines, ADODB, ADO and VBVM versions are all same

Comment: @HelO'Ween, we already patched  with RS.MoveFirst, but it do not make sense just for one machine code is having patch, we are looking at underlying reason why everything is same and RS.EOF and RS.BOF are not having same value? No VB6 code, due to IP have place ~pseudo code and not the real code.

Comment: It's not a "patch". Defensive programming, i.e. always make sure your application works from a known state, is simply good programming practice. I _seem_ to remember _(not sure though)_ that (ADODB.)Recordsets have no guaranteed cursor position, like records in a RDBMS have no guaranteed record positions (i.e. adding two records, it's not guaranteed that the 2nd record is physically stored _after_ the first record). So a precautionary `.MoveFirst` is something I always do.

Comment: @HelO'Ween, lets call is Defensive :), but inconsistent cursor position should happen on same system as well, we ran automation for long hours but never ever able to reproduce, but on other system it happens on each attempt.